# Inner join example in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I want to display all photos of each letter in image control. For the letter and photo, I considered two tables.now all letters are diplayed in datagridview. I want to by clicking on datagridview all ralatedphotos are diaplayed in image control.

I use the following code:

```
  private void Showimage()
    {            
        object item = GrdLater.SelectedItem;
        _id = int.Parse((GrdLater.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text);
        var query =(from u in db.Pictures
                  join uc in db.Letters on u.id equals _id
                 select new
                 {
                    u.Pic
                 });
        var result = query.ToList();
        if(result.Count == 1)
        {
            for (i = 0; i <= result.Count; i++)
            {
                byte [] imagearray = (byte [])result[0].Pic;
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                ms.Write(imagearray,0,imagearray.Length);
                System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.BeginInit();

                MemoryStream mss = new MemoryStream();
                image.Save(mss, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                mss.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin);
                bi.StreamSource = ms;
                bi.EndInit();
                image1.Source = bi;
            }
        }

    }
```

These codes do not show anything and returns the Null amount
i dont

Comment: Which line causes the issue?

Comment: Why are you checking if you get *exactly* one result, only to loop over all results in the next line (hint: it's always exactly one...)

Comment: Shouldn't you be joining the tables on values in the tables, like `u.id equals uc.PictureId`.  Better yet if you have navigation properties use them instead of join https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Comment: I solve this problems . now i have face this error."The image cannot be decoded. The image header might be corrupted."

Comment: now i have problem in loading image from database.

Comment: you can not helpe me?

Comment: those error is on   "bi.EndInit();"